# Hiding specific window (Enhanced Command+H)

Tags: macos, customization, window-manager

Is there a way, native or third party tool, to hide a specific window instead of all Application Windows, which is the current behavior of all macOS versions.

For example, when opening multiple Safari windows or Terminal windows, I just want to Command+H one of the windows, not all the application.

This is really helpful for multi-monitor setups.

Comment: How about Minimise instead? Cmd/M

Answer (score 1):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for but it is a start.

If you want to hide your current front most (active) window simply pressing <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd> <kbd>M</kbd> will do that.

That is the keyboard equivalent of clicking the yellow "Minimize" window button.

If you then need to "un-minimize" a window that you recently minimized that will require a trip to the mouse and the right size of the dock...

Comment: I’m aware of this and how to unhindered using a shortcut, but hiding is so much faster than a minimize animation.